# How to use bind (>>=) on function with multiple variables

Tags: haskell, monads

I am a newbie to haskell and functional programming. This might be a very simple thing, but I haven't found an answer while searching.

I have this function main here:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< (`rnd_select` 6) =<< readNumbers

readNumbers :: IO [(Int,Int,Int)]
readNumbers = makeTriples . map rInt . words <$> readFile "somefile"

rInt :: String -> Int
rInt = read

makeTriples :: [a] -> [(a,a,a)]
makeTriples [] = []
makeTriples (x:y:z:zs) = (x,y,z) : makeTriples zs

rnd_select :: [a] -> Int -> IO [a]
rnd_select _  0 = return []
rnd_select [] _ = return []
rnd_select xs count = do r <- randomRIO (0, (length xs)-1)
                         rest <- rnd_select (removeAt (r+1) xs) (count-1)
                         return ((xs!!r) : rest)

removeAt :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeAt _ [] = []
removeAt 1 (x:xs) = xs
removeAt k (x:xs) = let r = removeAt (k - 1) xs in x:r
```

This is wrapped in the IO-monad and that is what makes it hard when i want to use functions on the values.

Here i use the bind function to apply the input to the rnd_select function:

```
(`rnd_select` 6) =<< readNumbers
```

But in order to do that I have to partially apply it to a value.

I don't think it looks very good and I don't know how I would do it if the function had more variables.

So I want to know if there is a nicer way to apply values to functions such as these?

Comment: Well, you can swap the parameters of `rnd_select` so it becomes `rnd_select 6 =<< readNumbers "somefile"`.

Comment: It didn't work, but I made an error in my post. I added a function and fixed an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from defining the function such that the argument left out is the last argument, so that you can write

```
foobar = baz . foo 5 17 29 . bar
```

you can use a lambda to leave out arguments other than the last,

```
foobar = baz . (\x -> foo 5 17 x 29 41) . bar
```

but for the case of just two arguments, `flip` is a nice alternative,

```
main = print =<< flip rnd_select 6 =<< readNumbers
```

Comment: I found I could do this `main = print =<< (join $ rnd_select <$> readNumbers <*> (return 6))` but I don't think that looks good either. I would have to find a way to get rid of the parentheses if that would be a viable way.

Comment: @Altair That works, but I don't consider that nicer than what you had, I don't particularly like `IO (IO a)`. `main = print =<< ($ 6) =<< rnd_select <$> readNumbers` perhaps?

Comment: I think I have it figured out now. There seems to be no perfect way to do this, but at least it is possible to do it somewhat nice.

Answer (score 1):

Either swap `rnd_select` arguments, or use `flip rnd_select 6 =<< readNumbers`.

Comment: How do you swap arguments in this case? I tried but I couldn't do it.

Comment: @Altair Changing the argument order in the definition is meant.